# Can weak entity has more than one primary key if it has more than one strong entity?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database, composite-primary-key

If I have a weak entity with no attributes and has a four weak relationship with the owner entities and I want to design the relational schema for this weak entity, Can I take all primary keys of the strong entities that have relations with the weak entity and make them as primary keys for the weak entity?
I add an example below, my question is about the "Recon" entity.

[ER diagram(Recon entity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPEm2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrate the primary keys of the related strong entities into the primary key of the weak entity. The result is one (composite) primary key, not multiple primary keys<sup>1</sup>.

The resulting table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Recon (

    sin int REFERENCES Person,
    method int REFERENCES Method,
    name int REFERENCES Place,
    time REFERENCES TimeSlot,

    PRIMARY KEY (sin, method, name, time)

    -- Other fields and constraints...

);
```

NOTE: I'd consider introducing surrogate keys into the parent/strong entities, simply to make the weak entity's key leaner (e.g. introduce `PlaceId` and reference *it* from `Recon` instead of the natural key `name`).

---

<sup>1</sup> *In fact, there can be only one primary key per entity, although you could in theory have multiple alternate keys.*